# Displaying API response data in HTML

Tags: javascript, json, api, html-table

I am new to web scripting. Not at all expert in HTML advanced handling either. I have been working to get a response from API using Javascript and HTML. I get the response back from API.

However, I am not sure how I can display the data received in HTML. For example, I see that upon request, the API redirects me to my test page as desired - http://localhost/test.html

I want to display all parameters received from the API in a table in this HTML page. How can I achieve this? Here is the URL response I receive from API -

https://localhost/test.html?state=myState&scope=CustomApi&access_token=somerandomtokenjibberjabbergoeshere&expires_in=5184000&resource_server_base_uri=https%3a%2f%2fapi-b2.someapi.com%2fsomeAPI%2f&token_type=bearer

Here is my incomplete HTML -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Data received from API request
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>

<div class="container">
<div id="result" style="color:red"></div>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: The point of Stack Overflow is to ask for help with specific problems. It's not a site where you can ask others to write all your code for you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I am not asking anyone to write code for me. Perhaps I worded the question wrong. I am merely asking what approach will be best i.e. javascript, jquery etc.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else wondering, here is what I used

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

And then I called the variables as below

```
var token = getParameterByName('access_token'); // "value1"
var state = getParameterByName('state'); // "value2"
```